# table view как получить значение выделенной строки

Tags: qt

как при нажатии на строку в таблице получить значение первого столбца?

```
ui->discountsTableView->setModel(discountsModel);

void discounts::on_discountsTableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
   int znachenie = ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

разобрался:

```
QModelIndex currentDiscount  = ui->discountsTableView->currentIndex();
qDebug() << ui->discountsTableView->model()->data(ui->discountsTableView->model()->index(currentDiscount.row(),1),0);
```